# I there a Java equivalent to the Objective-C stringWithUTF8String:?

Tags: java, objective-c, nsstring

I need to convert the following from Objective-C to Java:

char key[] = {'9' + 1, 'U' + 2, '6' + 3, 'S' + 4, '7' + 5}
return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:key]

I'm not sure how to go about this.. does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, [public String(byte[] bytes, Charset charset)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29), 
the constructor of String that receives char[] and charset as parameters.

Comment: +1 For answering first, beat me by a couple of minutes so I decided to just post after lunch (didn't want to waste my ideone exampel) :)

Answer (score 0):

You use the [public String(byte[] bytes, String charsetName)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29) constructor and pass "UTF-8" as the charset. [Here is an example](http://ideone.com/jR2hK):

```
byte key[] = {'9' + 1, 'U' + 2, '6' + 3, 'S' + 4, '7' + 5};
return new String(key, "UTF-8");
```